# If I cancel my PS Plus subscription, will my game saves that I uploaded to the cloud disappear?

Tags: ps4, playstation-plus

Recently, I bought a 12 months subscription for PS Plus and uploaded some game saves to the cloud. Then, I canceled my subscription and requested a refund which was approved and bought a 3 months subscription instead. From what I read, if a PS Plus subscription expires, the game saves will stay on the cloud for six months.

As I have no backup of the game saves on my local drive(PS4), I was wondering if my game saves on the cloud be deleted if I cancel the subscription as opposed to it being expired?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Your game save file will be on their server for 6 months, no matter if you canceled subscription, or expired.
The only exception would be if you *choose* to delete save files on the cloud, though that isn't "automated" deletion.