# Will my Minecraft worlds stay in my game after my Playstation Plus expires?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, ps4, playstation-plus

My Playstation Plus subscription expires in about 3 more days. I have a Minecraft world that is in the cloud storage that Playstation Plus offers. When my subscription expires, will I still be able to play the world or will it get deleted from my game and only accessible if I get it from local storage? If so, is there any way I can take it out of storage so it's not deleted?

Answer (score 6):

According to a [previous post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/392935/if-i-cancel-my-ps-plus-subscription-will-my-game-saves-that-i-uploaded-to-the-c) on our site:

> Your game save file will be on their server for 6 months, no matter if you canceled subscription, or expired.
> The only exception would be if you choose to delete save files on the cloud, though that isn't "automated" deletion.

To answer if you can take it out of storage (i.e. download it to your Playstation), **yes** you can.  According to [Sony support](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/support/subscriptions/ps4-ps-plus-online-storage/#manage):

> 1. Select your local user and go to **Settings** > **Application Data Management** > **Saved data in Online Storage** > **Download to System Storage**.
> 2. Select the title and then the file you would like to download and select Yes to overwriting the system storage file.